# How to remove the second duplicate character in cPP string

Tags: c++, string

I want to remove the second appearance of a character in a string. so far I have made a function that is able to remove the first appearance.
For example: I want my function to do
`CACTUS --func--> CATUS` 
removing the second 'C'. But my function remove the first one
`CACTUS --func--> ACTUS` Can someone suggest something?

```
string  Remove_char( const string A,  const char a){
        string B =A;
                        int k = seq_search(B, a); // This returns the position of (a).
        if( k != -1){ // -1 is returned if (a) is not found in the string B.
                        for( int i =0; i < k; i++)
                                B = B + A[i];
                        for ( int i = k+1; i < A.length(); i++)
                                B = B + A[i];
        }
        return B;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `int k = seq_search(B, a); if(k != -1)` you should use `size_t k = B.find(a); if(k != std::string::npos)`

Comment: Before trying to code a process (algorithm), you should understand what the algorithm does. Can you describe (in English sentences, not C++ code) the process by which this code removes the first character in the string? How would you change that process to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a counter to count how many times `a` has been seen in the string and only skip that `char` if it's the second time it's seen.

```
std::string Remove_char(const std::string& A, const char a) {
    std::string B;
    B.reserve(A.size());
    
    unsigned seen = 0;
    for(char ch : A) {
        // add all characters that are not a, or if it is a,
        // add it if it's not the second time it's seen in the string
        if(ch != a || ++seen != 2) {
            B += ch;
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```

Alternatively, use the `std::string` member function `find` twice and create a new string from the substrings:

```
std::string Remove_char(const std::string& A, const char a) {
    if(auto pos = A.find(a); pos != std::string::npos) {
        if(pos = A.find(a, pos + 1); pos != std::string::npos) {
            return A.substr(0, pos) + A.substr(pos + 1);
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

Comment: Hello! @Ted . I have never seen this type of use to if statement````if( code ; code)```` can you please explain what that ' ; ' does? or where can I study how its used. Thanks

Comment: @MeharjeetSingh That's an [`if` with an _init-statement_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). It requires C++17 and if you can't use C++17, just move the init-statement to the line before the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a multiset. Although @TedLyngmo's solution looks far simpler to me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using std::string;

string Remove_char(const string A, const char a)
{
    string ret{};
    std::multiset<char> chars_already_in_string{};
    for (const char& c : A)
    {
        if (c != a || chars_already_in_string.count(c) != 1)
        // This other version would remove every second occurence of any character
        // The use of a multiset would be more justified here
        //if (chars_already_in_string.count(c) != 1)
        {
            ret.push_back(c);
        }
        chars_already_in_string.insert(c);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Remove_char("CACTUSCCS", 'C');
    return 0;
}
```

Online test: https://godbolt.org/z/M4Y3aa

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, sorry! Misread the question :) I'll remove my answer then, yes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Your solution is far better and simpler!

Comment: That's in the eye of the beholder. It never hurts with alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it works

```
std::string SecondDelete(std::string path, char target)
{
    int nth = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; path.size(); i++)
    {
        if (target == path[i])
            nth++;
        if (nth == 2)
        {
            return path.substr(0, i) + path.substr(i+1, path.size());           
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```